# How can I get my fragment code onClick() get recognized my the main activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am new to android studio. I am sitting for a couple days on my work, but I didn't manage my Button on a Fragment to work as expected.

My structure:

- For my fragment, I have a java-class where my method for the Button is defined. (onClick())
- I have a main-activity which contains/knows/... the fragment/the java-class of fragment

When I click on my button, the app crashes.
I think it has to do something with binding the fragment to the main activity. I thought i did that already by saying:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_page01, container, false);
return rootView;
}
```

in the main activity.

But it seems I forget something important. I would appreciate it if someone can help me out.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.yasars.my_fernbedienung;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.webkit.HttpAuthHandler;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private SeekBar mySoundBar;
    private TextView textView;
    private HttpRequest httpRequest;
    private String ipaddress;

    private void initializeVariables() {
        mySoundBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.mySoundBar); // initiate the Seekbar
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.volumeView); // initiate volume print
        ipaddress = "192.168.56.1";
        httpRequest = new HttpRequest(ipaddress, 4, true); //4 stands for 4 milliseconds to wait for a response
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

    }

    private static final String Tag = "myDebugAid";

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;


    @Override
    public void addContentView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        super.addContentView(view, params);
        Log.i(Tag, "addContentView");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.i(Tag, "onStop");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Log.i(Tag, "onSaveInstanceState");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.i(Tag, "onPause");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i(Tag, "onResume");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initializeVariables();

        mySoundBar.setMax(100); // 100 maximum value for the Seek bar
        mySoundBar.setProgress(10);

        textView.setText(mySoundBar.getProgress() + "/" + mySoundBar.getMax());

        mySoundBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            int progress = 0;

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progressValue, boolean fromUser) {
                progress = progressValue;
                textView.setText(progress + "/" + seekBar.getMax());
                try {
                    httpRequest.execute("volume=" + progress);
                } catch (IOException | JSONException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
                }


                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Changing volume", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //we don't need above line. It is irritating for the user
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                textView.setText(progress + "/" + seekBar.getMax());
                try {
                    httpRequest.execute("volume=" + progress);
                } catch (IOException | JSONException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
                }

                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Started tracking volume", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //we don't need above line. It is irritating for the user
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                textView.setText(progress + "/" + seekBar.getMax());
                try {
                    httpRequest.execute("volume=" + progress);
                } catch (IOException | JSONException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
                }
            }
        });


        //HttpRequest httpReq = new HttpRequest(); // an instance of HttpRequest

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        try {
            httpRequest.execute("channelMain=8a");
        } catch (IOException | JSONException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

//    seekBarInstanceVariable.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener()) {
//
//    } //This method is used to notify the user changes/actions in the SeekBar.

    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progresValue, boolean fromUser) {

    } //This listener method will be invoked if any change is made in the SeekBar.

    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    } //This listener method will be invoked at the start of user’s touch event. Whenever a user
    // touch the thumb for dragging this method will automatically called.

    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    } //This listener method will be invoked at the end of user touch event. Whenever a user stop
    // dragging the thump this method will be automatically called.


    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 1) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_page01, container, false);
                return rootView;
            } else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 2) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_page02, container, false);
                return rootView;
            } else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 3) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_page03, container, false);
                return rootView;
            } else {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
                TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
                textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
                return rootView;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Home";
                case 1:
                    return "Favoriten";
                case 2:
                    return "Sender";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

SubPage01.java:

```
package layout;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.Map;

import com.example.yasars.my_fernbedienung.HttpRequest;
import com.example.yasars.my_fernbedienung.R;

import org.json.JSONException;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link SubPage01.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link SubPage01#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class SubPage01 extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    private Button button_tri_right;
    private Button button_tri_left;
    private HttpRequest httpRequest;
    private String ipaddress;
    private int onChannel = 1; //it is for the channel recognition.
    private Map<String, String> ChannelMap;

    private void initializeHttpRequest() {
        ipaddress = "192.168.56.1";
        httpRequest = new HttpRequest(ipaddress, 4, true);
    }

    private void fillChannelContainer() {

        ChannelMap.put("1", "8a");
        ChannelMap.put("2", "8b");
        ChannelMap.put("3", "8c");
        ChannelMap.put("4", "22a");
        ChannelMap.put("5", "22b");
        ChannelMap.put("6", "22c");
        ChannelMap.put("7", "22d");
        ChannelMap.put("8", "34a");
        ChannelMap.put("9", "34b");
        ChannelMap.put("10", "34c");
        ChannelMap.put("11", "34d");
        ChannelMap.put("12", "37a");
        ChannelMap.put("13", "37b");
        ChannelMap.put("14", "37c");

/*        ChannelMap.put("Phoenix", "8a");
        ChannelMap.put("BR", "8b");
        ChannelMap.put("SWR", "8c");
        ChannelMap.put("ZDF", "22a");
        ChannelMap.put("3Sat", "22b");
        ChannelMap.put("ZDFinfo" "22c");
        ChannelMap.put("KiKa", "22d");
        ChannelMap.put("RTL", "34a");
        ChannelMap.put("RTL2", "34b");
        ChannelMap.put("Super RTL", "34c");
        ChannelMap.put("Vox", "34d");
        ChannelMap.put("Das Erste", "37a");
        ChannelMap.put("hr", "37b");
        ChannelMap.put("arte", "37c");*/
    }

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public SubPage01() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment SubPage01.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static SubPage01 newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        SubPage01 fragment = new SubPage01();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
        initializeHttpRequest();
        fillChannelContainer();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_page01, container, false);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_page01, container, false);

        Button b1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.right_triangle_button);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.right_triangle_button: {
                        if (onChannel == 14) {
                            onChannel = 1;
                        } else {
                            onChannel = onChannel + 1;
                        }
                        String tmpString = String.valueOf(onChannel);
                        try {
                            httpRequest.execute("channelMain=" + ChannelMap.get(tmpString));
                            System.out.println(ChannelMap.get(tmpString));
                        } catch (IOException | JSONException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });


        Button b2 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.left_triangle_button);
        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.left_triangle_button: {
                        if (onChannel == 1)

                        {
                            onChannel = 14;
                        } else

                        {
                            onChannel = onChannel - 1;
                        }

                        String tmpString = String.valueOf(onChannel);
                        try

                        {
                            httpRequest.execute("channelMain=" + ChannelMap.get(tmpString));
                            System.out.println(ChannelMap.get(tmpString));
                        } catch (IOException | JSONException |
                                IllegalArgumentException e)

                        {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        return v;
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        button_tri_right = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.right_triangle_button); //this is necessary because you can't
        button_tri_left = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.left_triangle_button);   //use findViewById() directly, like in
        //activities.
    }

    /*// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonRightPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
        String tmpString = String.valueOf(onChannel);
        try {
            httpRequest.execute("channelMain=" + ChannelMap.get(tmpString));
        } catch (IOException | JSONException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
        }
        onChannel = onChannel + 1;
    }


    public void onButtonLeftPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
        String tmpString = String.valueOf(onChannel);
        try {
            httpRequest.execute("channelMain=" + ChannelMap.get(tmpString));
            System.out.println(ChannelMap.get(tmpString));
        } catch (IOException | JSONException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
        }
        onChannel = onChannel + 1;
    }*/

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }


}
```

fragment_sub_page01.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="layout.SubPage01">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/left_triangle_button"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="-100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/triangle_button_left"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:backgroundTint="#076a24" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/right_triangle_button"
        android:layout_width="60dp"

        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/triangle_button_right"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        app:backgroundTint="#076a24" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Sendung"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="-100dp"
        />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Sender"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="-150dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:ems="4"
        android:hint="Nr."
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

</FrameLayout>
```

I tried some possible solutions but didn't manage to resolve my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: the talk is about buttons:

- left_triangle_button
- right_triangle_button

Comment: Provide your crash log

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because you are trying to execute network request on UI thread (Check you crash log).
Network requests should be done on background thread.